# What is the purpose of covariance matrix in multivariate (normal) distribution?

Tags: statistics, multivariable-calculus, normal-distribution

Why we care about covariance matrix in multivariate normal distribution? When we are talking about single random variable **X ~ N(mu, std)** the parameters are **mu** and **std**. But when we have vector **(X1, X2, X3, ..., Xn) ~ N(mu, cov)** we have *n-dim* vector **mu** and *n x n* covariance matrix **cov**. Why don't we just have *n-dim* vector of **stds** for second parameter?

Comment: Standard deviations / variances represent how spread each random variable tend to be around their respective means. When you have multiple random variables, you also want to know whether variable 1 tend to be higher than its mean when variable 2 is higher than its mean or the opposite etc.. Covariance is a measure of this tendency.

Comment: Heights are not normally distributed but suppose they were and you looked at the distribution of heights of parents compared to those of their adult children (with an adjustment for gender).  You would see a partial relationship due to genetics which can be measured with covariance.  If you then wanted to generate some artificial values with the same distribution, you would want to take this covariance into account and so it is part of the specification of the distribution.

Comment: Suppose we have means and standard variations of 2 variables X1 and X2. With that information, can we answer this question: when X1 increases, does X2 increase or decrease?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to see why is to think about the bivariate case.

If you have just two univariate normal distributions (one for the $x$ axis and one for the $y$ axis on a plane), you would always end up with an ellipse with major and minor radiuses perfectly aligned with the $x$ and $y$ axis.

There would be no way to represent an elliptical distribution that is tilted or spread (diagonally for example) in the $xy$ plane. **The orientation of the ellipse of the distribution is encoded in the covariance matrix.**

The covariance matrix encodes the variance as well as the orientation of the elliptical distribution so that you can have arbitrary multivariate normal distributions.

You can see two univariate distributions in the walls on the image below. The resulting elliptical distribution is however slightly tilted because there is some correlation between them. (Example taken from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution).

[image]

If you had to plot these univariate distributions without any correlation that ellipse would be aligned with the axes.

Technically you don't need a covariance matrix to do all of this in 2D. You could represent the orientation with a single vector separately.

However in higher dimensions you need the angles between each pair of axes and thus the covariance matrix is a more convenient representation.

Further it is worth mentioning that the covariance matrix encodes redundant information, so it is not the most compact way to represent orientation. You could indeed do this somewhat more efficiently with vectors.

In fact the covariance matrix has restrictions imposed on it (positive-definiteness) that suggests some orientations it can encode are invalid.